# video.js starting video after 1 minute

Tags: javascript, php, video.js

I have this piece of code that runs a video on my page, I would like to start the video after 60 seconds, but how do i do this?

```
                    <video id="video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="720" height="576" poster="<?php echo $pic1; ?>" data-setup="{}">
            <source src="<?php echo $filename; ?>" type='video/mp4'>
            <track kind="chapters" src="<?php echo $chapters; ?>" srclang="en" label="English" default="default" >
            <p class="vjs-no-js">
              To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
              <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
            </p>
          </video>
```

Comment: hint: [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), [HTMLMediaElement.play()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript file:

```
const mainVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
let playVideoAfter = 60; // seconds

setTimeout(() => mainVideo.play(), playVideoAfter * 1000);
```

This code selects the video, then calls the play() function on it after 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)